# What's the best way to separate lazy loaded feature modules in Angular for large teams & projects?

Tags: angular

I am migrating a large application into Angular and the I would like to separate the routes into lazy-loaded routed feature modules. I apologise in advance for the large series of questions.

The feature seems great and easy to implement, however I am struggling to understand how to tie together a large project.

I can set up one git repo, and have all of the modules in that repo, but then we will have cross team release issues.

Is it possible to split the feature modules into separate git repos?

Should each repo push to a private npm repository?

If I do that should I create angular libraries via the CLI for each module, or just push the TypeScript source?

Will the `loadChildren` parameter respond to an npm module path?

How would doing that impact AOT?

How would you structure a CI/CD cycle?